# How I can restart all the programs configuration?

Tags: configuration, restart

I want to know if there is any way to reset all the settings of the programs what I've installed. For example, restart the configuration of Gparted or Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 3):

Inside your Home folder there's a `.config` folder some software puts their configuration files there, also in your Home folder there are several hidden folders look for the correct ones and delete them.